# Cannot read property of undefined how to work around this in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I execute a component and this component fills the value `profilePicRef` once. However, I only want to display the `Upload` button when `profilePicRef.current.preview` is also no longer zero. However, I always get the error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'preview' of undefined`. My question is, how can I now say if it is undefined, then don't take it into account and if it is not zero show it.

```
<PhotoFileHandler ref={profilePicRef} />
                        {
                                profilePicRef.current.preview !== null &&
                                <button className="button is-primary is-outlined" type="butto" 
                                    onClick={() => { onClickUpload(profilePicRef); 
                                    setActiveModal(''); }}>
                                    <i className="fas fa-file-image"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
                            }
```

PhotoFileHandler

```
import React, { useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, } from "react";


function PhotoFileHandler(props, ref) {
  const [picName, setPicName] = useState(null);
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);
  const [isPreview, setIsPreview] = useState(true);

  const fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
        ....
        setPicName(event.target.files[0].name);
        setPreview(reader.result);
        setIsPreview(true);

      
      }
    }
    catch (err) {
    }
  };


  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    isPreview,
    preview,
    picName,
    checkProfilPicture() {
      if (!preview) {
        setIsPreview(false);
        return false;
      }
      else {
        setIsPreview(true);
        return true;

      }
    },
    getImage() {
      return preview
    },
    removePreview() {
      setIsPreview(false)
      setPreview(null);
      setPicName(null);
    }
  }),
  );


  return (
    <div>
       
          <input class="file-input" type="file" name="resume" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg, .jfif"
            onChange={fileSelectedHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};
// eslint-disable-next-line
PhotoFileHandler = forwardRef(PhotoFileHandler);
export default PhotoFileHandler;
```

Comment: Please show PhotoFileHandler

Comment: do an optional chaining `profilePicRef.current?.preview`

Comment: Also please format using 4 indents and trim your lines. And `type="butto"` ?

Comment: @Viet please see my edit.

Comment: @nithinpp The error no longer occurs, but the button is permanently displayed.

Comment: So I have a constant `isPreview` and if this is true then it should be displayed, non-zero `preview` should also work. But `isPreview` would be better.

Comment: @Mr.Hankey did you test the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Is important to do with `ref`?

**Alternative 0: Without Ref, Parent State**

Alternative with `state`, you can see how it works here: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-gates-ctw6m?file=/src/App.js) :

- Include one variable "file" `const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = React.useState(null)`
- Send the setter function to `PhotoFileHandler`, I did something like: `<PhotoFileHandler onImage={setSelectedFile} />`
- In PhotoFileHandler I did:

```js
const fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
  props.onImage(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

**Alternative 1: Force update with Parent State**

If you need the `ref`, one workaround can be the trigger it when change it, like: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-butterfly-iqmw3?file=/src/App.js,

- Define in your parent component one state: `const [wasUpdated, setWasUpdated] = React.useState("");`
- Include this in your validation to show the preview and upload button:

```js
profilePicRef.current &&
  profilePicRef.current.preview !== null &&
  wasUpdated && (
    <AllHtml />
  )
)
```

- Send the setter to the children `<PhotoFileHandler ref={profilePicRef} onChange={setWasUpdated} />`
- In the children component you can trigger the event after updating `preview`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.onChange(preview);
}, [preview]);
```